# Runing php code after time interval countown set by javascript reaches 0

Tags: javascript, php, html

i need help running php code trough javascript. Im trying to make autoplay for the videos pulled from my database.

There you can see youtube song playing in the background, using youtube API, php and javascript i pulled out song duration into countdown script with result is song duration shown in seconds counting down to 0.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    var timeleft = <?php echo $vreme[$i];?>;
                    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
                        timeleft--;
                        document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;       
                        if(timeleft <= 0)

                        clearInterval(downloadTimer);


                    },1000);
                </script>
```

$vreme represents song duration pulled from youtube api.

Next up i have a button that when pressed will go to the next or previous song, like this :

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">

                <input  class="button-warning pure-button col-md-6" type="submit" name="prev" value="Previous" <?php if($i == 0){?>disabled <?php }  ?>>
                <input class="button-warning pure-button col-md-6" type="submit" name="next" value="Next" <?php if($i+1 == $aco){?>disabled <?php }?>><br>



            </form>
```

Php code working with session for pulling the next or previous song info from my database is :

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $link = array();
                $yid = array();
                $vreme = array();

                // output data of each row   
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    $link[]=$row["link"];
                    $yid[]=$row["title"];
                    $vreme[]=$row["time"];

                } 
                $i=0;


                if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
                    $_SESSION['$i'] += 1 ;  
                    $i=$_SESSION['$i']; 
                    session_regenerate_id();
                    }elseif (isset($_POST['prev'])) {
                    $_SESSION['$i'] -= 1 ;
                    $i=$_SESSION['$i'];
                    session_regenerate_id();
                }
                else {
                    $_SESSION['$i'] = 0;
                }

            ?>
```

So thats basically how everything there works.

Now what i don't know is basically the question from the title. Is there a way to open next song from my database when time counter from script hits 0 ? Can i call for php page or a code after condition in javascript ? `if(timeleft <= 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mimic a button click of the "next" button...

```
if (timeleft <= 0) {
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);

    // find and click the "next" button
    document.querySelector("input[type=submit][name=next]").click();
}
```

Comment: Have you added the curly braces around the code, like in my answer?  `if (something) { <-- that and that --> }`

Comment: Yeah sory, i did not open the block. Thanks a lot works like a charm!

Comment: No worries - happy to help :)